# How to Pass data between ViewModels WPF, MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have loaded image in MainWindow, Now i am trying to display input image in ChildWindow when it is invoked but unable to get input image to ChildWindow.

How to pass input image loaded in MainWindowViewModel to ChildWindowViewModel

What method i have to follow to load input image and pass it to multiple viewmodel

Here is my code

MainWindowViewModel

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public ICommand OpenImg { get; set; }

    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        OpenImg = new RelayCommand(LoadImage);
    }

    private BitmapImage _image;
    public BitmapImage Image
    {
        get { return _image; }
        set
        {
            _image = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Image");
        }
    }

    private void LoadImage()
    {
        OpenFileDialog op = new OpenFileDialog();
        op.Title = "Select a Picture";
        op.Filter = "Images (*.BMP;*.JPG;*.GIF;*.PNG;*.TIFF)|*.BMP;*.JPG;*.GIF;*.PNG;*.TIFF|" +
            "All files (*.*)|*.*";
        op.Multiselect = true;
        if (op.ShowDialog() == true)
        {
            Image = new BitmapImage(new Uri(op.FileName));
        }
    }       

    private RelayCommand _childWin;
    public ICommand ChildWin
    {
        get
        {
            if (_childWin == null)
            {
                _childWin = new RelayCommand(DisplayChildWin);
            }
            return _childWin;
        }
    }

    private void DisplayChildWin()
    {
        ChildWindow childWindow = new ChildWindow();
        childWindow.Show();
    }
}
```

ChildWindowViewModel

```
public class ChildWindowViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public ChildWindowViewModel()
    {
        MainWindowViewModel = new MainWindowViewModel();

        Imge = MainWindowViewModel.Image;
    }

    private BitmapImage _imge;
    public BitmapImage Imge
    {
        get { return _imge; }
        set
        {
            _imge = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Imge");
        }
    }

    private MainWindowViewModel _mainWindowViewModel;
    public MainWindowViewModel MainWindowViewModel
    {
        get
        {
            return _mainWindowViewModel;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != _mainWindowViewModel)
            {
                _mainWindowViewModel = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("MainWindowViewModel");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, this post may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23505916/mvvm-how-to-pass-observablecollection-to-other-viewmodels

Comment: It is wrong to create a new MainWindowViewModel in the ChildWindowViewModel. Instead when opening the child window, create a ChildWindowViewModel and pass it a reference to the MainWindowViewModel. Then assign the ChildWindowViewModel to the DataContext of the ChildWindow.

Comment: Or remove the MainWindowViewModel property from ChildWindowViewModel and directly pass the Image.

Comment: If there isn't anything else than the Image in ChildWindowViewModel, you may even drop it completely and just use an anonymous class like `childWindow.DataContext = new { Image = Image };`

Comment: you can pass the image as a parameter to child VM.

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways you could handle this, with various trade-offs. To keep things simple, and work with what you have provided, I would do as follows.

I am assuming that in your `ChildWindow` class you set the `DataContext` to `new ChildWindowViewModel();` or otherwise create a `StaticResource` in your XAML. This solution would require you to remove that.

Simply require the `BitmapImage` in the constructor of the `ChildWindowViewModel` and remove the knowledge of the `MainWindowViewModel` from it.

```
public class ChildWindowViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public ChildWindowViewModel(BitmapImage image)
    {
        _imge = image;
    }

    private BitmapImage _imge;
    public BitmapImage Imge
    {
        get { return _imge; }
        set
        {
            _imge = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Imge");
        }
    }
}
```

Now in your `MainWindowViewModel` you can update the `DisplayChildWin` method as follows:

```
private void DisplayChildWin()
{
    var childWindow = new ChildWindow();
    var childWindowViewModel = new ChildWindowViewModel(Imge);
    childWindow.DataContext = childWindowViewModel;
    childWindow.Show();
}
```

I would try to move towards removing the creation of the `ChildWindow` entierly from your `MainWindowViewModel` class. This is something best handled by a factory that could be injected into the `MainWindowViewModel`. [Adaptive Code via C#](https://www.microsoftpressstore.com/store/adaptive-code-via-c-sharp-agile-coding-with-design-9780133979756) is a great book that covers Dependency Inversion well, SOLID, and some simple abstractions.

Comment: After reading the comments, this appears to be along the lines of what @Clemens  suggests.

Comment: Implementing INotifyPropertyChanged for the ChildWindowViewModel's Image property seems pointless when it's only set in the constructor. It should be a readonly property then.

Comment: Yes I agree. I think there are a few 'should be's here, but I didn't want to detract from a simple solution to a simple question. That's why I stopped at recommending some further reading ^^.